# making an array with the length of chars in unicode

Tags: java, unicode

I am  writing a code in java , where every time a user types 1 character it checks if it is one of the special characters

```
char a = getFromInput();

if(a = '$'){
  //do something

}else if(a = '@'){
  //do something


}else if(a = '#'){
  //do something


}else if(a ='~'){
  //do something


}else if(a ='^'){
  //do something


}else if(a ='&'){
  //do something


}... // the if statements go on
```

However It came to me that this is inefficient since it uses to much if statements . To solve this, I came up with the idea to make an array of bytes with the length of the unicode index of the last special character

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[1000] 

// the length 1000 is because I thought most of the special characters are 
// index of less that 1000 in unicode UTF-8 mapping

Functor[] functors;

// functors are just objects that i made that contain function

char a = getFromInput();
if(byte[a] >100){
   // do nothing when byte[char] is larger that 100 
}else {
    functors[byte[a]].func();
}
```

So basically what i'm trying to do is using the char variable as index of the array. What i'm curious is

1. Would using more that 100 if statements for every character the user inputs be okay? are there any suggestions ?
2. I know making an array would cost more memory but would it be better than using multiple (tons of ) if statement with respect to the performance ?

Comment: Are these "do somethings" simple? What is your goal in checking for these characters? Does each character do something completely different?

Comment: yes it does , they trigger special functions

Comment: What about `if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(ch))` or any of those other [`Character` methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) that allow you to look at the type & properties of characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would using more that 100 if statements for every character the user inputs be okay? are there any suggestions ?

It is up to you to decide what is "okay" ... unless you provide us with the criteria.

However, there are a variety of other alternatives to lots of `if` statements:

- a `switch` statement
- `if` statements that test character ranges rather than individual characters
- an array of `SomeFunction` where the character is the array index
- an array of codes (indexed by character) that maps characters to code values (e.g. `SomeEnum`) that you then switch on
- an array of a custom `PairOfCharAndFunction` class sorted on the character field that you search using binary search
- a `HashMap<Character, SomeFunction>`
- a `TreeMap<Character, SomeFunction>` or `TreeMap<Character, SomeEnum>` that you use to implement range-based checking: hint the `floorEntry` method.

And so on.

---

> I know making an array would cost more memory but would it be better than using multiple (tons of ) if statement with respect to the performance ?

Yes it would, provided that the array (or similar mapping data structure; see above) only needs to be set up once.

It is theoretically possible for the Java JIT compiler to turn a sequence of `if` tests into the machine equivalent of a `switch` in some circumstances, but I don't think it does.

> ... would a switch statement be generally faster than if statements?

Generally yes.  If not, the JIT compiler will translate the `switch` into a sequence of `if` statements.  (In fact, there is a time versus code-space trade-off here.)

Comment: Thanks for the good opinions. However I am curious, would a switch statement be generally faster than if statements? and the third option you mentioned .. did you mean just directly making an array of functors that are indexed by chars? wouldn't that be just a modification of what i did above?

Comment: Not a modification.  It is exactly the same.  I am trying to list all of the reasonable alternatives that I can think of ... including yours.

Answer (score 1):

You should check range of characters instead of checking one character after the other. Something like

```
if (a < 'a' && a > 'z') {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Yep, that is a good suggestion but, some special characters in the unicode table are positioned intermittently. I do admit checking several ranges would be better than my code though

Comment: I never said that you will be able to put everything into the same range :-) It will still be faster this way